# Finding the parent function of the integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to deal with this integral?
$\int{ \frac{dx}{(x^{2}+2x+10)^{3}}}$

Comment: Start by completing the square. Then use the identity:

$tan^2(x)+1=sec^2(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $u=x+1,$ then substitute $v=3 u,$ then let $v = \tan \theta.$